# I would like to calculate euclidian distance and put it in a list. I recive range error, what I'm missing?

Tags: python, numpy, loops

I would like to evaluate the euclidian distance from a fixed point to several points, I want to do it through a loop. Why is not working?  I also tried without the '-1' for the range but still not working

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
vettore = np.array(np.mat('1 2; 3 4;6,7;8,9;10,12'))
posizione= np.array(np.mat('2,2'))


codio= []
for i in range(0,len(vettore)-1):
    codio[i]=distance.euclidean(vettore[i],posizione)
    
codio


>>> IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `distance_matrix`:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix

distance_matrix(vettore, posizione).ravel()
```

Output:

```
array([ 1.        ,  2.23606798,  6.40312424,  9.21954446, 12.80624847])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `append` to add item into `list`

```py
codio= []
for i in range(0,len(vettore)-1):
    codio.append(distance.euclidean(vettore[i], posizione))
```

However a better approach is to use `distance_metrics` as @Quang's answer.